# how to get detail base on id with retrofi

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I get all data from my api and load them in recycle view . now I want to get detail of data.
when user click of list , i get id and want to get the detail base on the id user click .

this is my url :  http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=3e974fca&i=tt037

this is my id : tg037

public interface APIService {

```
@GET("?apikey=3e974fca&i=")

Call<Example> getDetails(@Query("imdbID") String id);
```

}

and id the value that I pass from my adapter into here:

```
    private void loginRetrofitFlag(String id) {
    //final SampleLang login = new SampleLang(src, target);
    Call<Example> call1 = mAPIService.getDetails(id);
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            Example loginResponse = response.body();

            Log.e("test",   loginResponse.getActors());
     


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

with this code It return null and I know that my problem is here :

```
   Call<Example> getDetails(@Query("imdbID") String id);
```

Comment: Where do u getting null value? show some log or info related with null value

Comment: My log return null , but loginResponse  is not null

Comment: then where u are getting null value. please check the api response in browser or postman

Comment: api is correct and i get the value in postmain correctly , but I dont know how to write my interface  . when I write my endpoints complete is ok , but I want to get id when user click in my list

Comment: I think this part is not correct Call<Example> getDetails(@Query("imdbID") String id);

Comment: remove = from url, no need of = in url , replace with this @GET("?apikey=3e974fca&i") and @Query("i")

Comment: yes , thank you , it is correct now I get values